# Python Flask, how to detect a SSE client disconnect from front end Javascript

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events

Maybe this is a problem in Flask, there is no way to handle disconnection event on the server side.

In Response class, there is a method named "call_on_close", where we can add a function without argument, e.g. on_close(), it will be fired when the response object's close method called, but this doesn't happen when I call EventSource.close() from the client side in Javascript.

code on server side:

```
from flask import Response
r = Response(stream(), ...)
r.call_on_close(on_close)
return r 

def on_close():
  print "response is closed!"

def stream():
  ...  # subscribe to redis
  for message in pubsub.listen():
    ....
    yield 'data: %s\n\n' % message
```

on client side: add unload handler to page with SSE

```
$(window).unload(
  function() {
    sse.close();
  }
}
```

Anything is wrong?

Any suggestions or solution with code is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you happen to find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

The generator receives a `GeneratorExit` exception, and that's when you know it will exit. For example:

```
def stream():
    try:
        i = 0
        while True:
            yield 'Hello {}!'.format(i)
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        # Called after a GeneratorExit, cleanup here
        i = 0


@app.route('/messages')
def messages():
    return Response(stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

Will yield a infinite stream of `"Hello!"`, and you will know when it's done, where you can run cleanup code. If your generator blocks the thread, it will need to be unblocked in some way (maybe pushing a dummy item) so that the generator can be closed.

Comment: This particular example seems to work, but not in conjunction with a nonblocking Redis pubsub.get_message() loop

Comment: From your answer, I assume you never did a `yield` `if not message`. I'm guessing it's because you need the `yield` for the caller to have a chance at stopping the generator, and for the generator to know it was stopped.

Comment: Yes, exactly! This is also the reason why using blocking listener functions is impossible, unless there are frequent ping/alive messages that cause a yield

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem with Rails Live Controllers. The problem is that the framework doesn't seem to detect that the connection is closed until it attempts to send an Event to the client.

One approach is to send periodic "heartbeat" events to the client. I'm presently using this successfully on my Rails project with an interval of 60 seconds. I have a separate thread that "emits" these heartbeats into Redis, that my controller has subscribed to.

An alternative to the threaded approach, is to wrap the Redis pubsub block with a timeout (again, say 60 seconds). And then send the heartbeat event to the client - followed by another pubsub call. The downside to this approach, is you may miss an event while you're not subscribed.

There's more on the threading approach here:
[Redis + ActionController::Live threads not dying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970458/redis-actioncontrollerlive-threads-not-dying)

Answer (score 2):

To extend on @Lonami's answer, a `yield` is required when working with a nonblocking function that returns data

```py
def stream():
    try:
        pubsub = red.pubsub()
        pubsub.subscribe('chat')
        #for message in pubsub.listen():#This doesn't work because it's blocking
        while True:
            message = pubsub.get_message()

            if not message:
                # The yield is necessary for this to work!
                # In my case I always send JSON encoded data
                # An empty response might work, too.
                yield "data: {}\n\n"
                sleep(0.1)
                continue

            # If the nonblocking get_message() returned something, proceed normally
            yield 'data: %s\n\n' % message["data"]
    finally:
        print("CLOSED!")
        # Your closing logic here (e.g. marking the user as offline in your database)


@app.route('/messages')
def messages():
    return Response(stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

Comment: But this isn't a non-blocking solution. You're using `time.sleep(0.1)`. Once the SSE is initialized you won't be able to send other requests to the server.
You should change `def stream()` to `async def stream()` and instead of `time.sleep(0.1)` use `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)`.

Comment: Actually, my solution above may not work with Flask. I'm using FastAPI which is async.